# query with custom field

Tags: post-meta

I figured out with my jquery slider. Need to help (:

my query is:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&orderby=post_date&order=desc'); while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $imaj = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'manset', true); ?>

<?php the_permalink()?>
<img src="<?php echo $imaj; ?>" alt="" />

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

with this query, **the query** print all posts. But i would like to display just if the post has "manset" custom field in it. how can i do that

( sorry about my bad english )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search would have directed you to this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters